# Parser generator for JavaME

Tags: code-generation, parsing, java-me, lexer

First: I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821501/parser-generator-for-java-with-the-following-requirements) SO question but unfortunately there is no mention of JavaME

I am looking for a parser/lexer generator that produces code that can run on the Blackberry and its (obnoxious) JavaME.

E.g. at first I thought I could use ANTLR however it seems the run-time library is not compatible with JavaME

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it was not that much work to adapt the ANTLR 3.2 run-time for JavaMe, I left out some things but ported most of the sources. It took about a day to rewrite for those who are facing the same problem.

Changes included:

- replacing List/ArrayList with Vector
- replacing Map/Hashmap with Hashtable
- removing file handling (not needed -in my case)
- removing cloneable (not supported)
- removing all generics, replaced with normal, concrete classes
- adding simple function to do string
  replaceAll
- removed debugging module (not needed
  -in my case)