# How to segment file input into portions in Java

Tags: java, delimiter

I need to separate each rule in the file below.
How can I do that in Java?

This is the file contents

```
rule apt_regin_2011_32bit_stage1 {
meta:
copyright = "Kaspersky Lab"
 description = "Rule to detect Regin 32 bit stage 1 loaders"
 version = "1.0"
 last_modified = "2014-11-18"
strings:
$key1={331015EA261D38A7}
$key2={9145A98BA37617DE}
$key3={EF745F23AA67243D}
$mz="MZ"
condition:
($mz at 0) and any of ($key*) and filesize < 300000
}


rule apt_regin_rc5key {
meta:
copyright = "Kaspersky Lab"
 description = "Rule to detect Regin RC5 decryption keys"
 version = "1.0"
 last_modified = "2014-11-18"
strings:
$key1={73 23 1F 43 93 E1 9F 2F 99 0C 17 81 5C FF B4 01}
$key2={10 19 53 2A 11 ED A3 74 3F C3 72 3F 9D 94 3D 78}
condition:
any of ($key*)
}



rule apt_regin_vfs {
meta:
copyright = "Kaspersky Lab"
 description = "Rule to detect Regin VFSes"
 version = "1.0"
 last_modified = "2014-11-18"
strings:
$a1={00 02 00 08 00 08 03 F6 D7 F3 52}
$a2={00 10 F0 FF F0 FF 11 C7 7F E8 52}
$a3={00 04 00 10 00 10 03 C2 D3 1C 93}
$a4={00 04 00 10 C8 00 04 C8 93 06 D8}
condition:
($a1 at 0) or ($a2 at 0) or ($a3 at 0) or ($a4 at 0)
}


rule apt_regin_dispatcher_disp_dll {
meta:
copyright = "Kaspersky Lab"
 description = "Rule to detect Regin disp.dll dispatcher"
 version = "1.0"
 last_modified = "2014-11-18"
strings:
$mz="MZ"
 $string1="shit"
 $string2="disp.dll"
 $string3="255.255.255.255"
 $string4="StackWalk64"
 $string5="imagehlp.dll"
condition:
($mz at 0) and (all of ($string*))
}
```

As per seen in the file, I need to separate each of the 4 rules found in the file input, any idea how can i do this?
Please be patient with me. I am a newbie
Appreciated in advance!

After separating all of the 4 rules, I need to put each rule into an arraylist.

For example:
Arraylist[0]

```
rule apt_regin_2011_32bit_stage1 {
meta:
copyright = "Kaspersky Lab"
 description = "Rule to detect Regin 32 bit stage 1 loaders"
 version = "1.0"
 last_modified = "2014-11-18"
strings:
$key1={331015EA261D38A7}
$key2={9145A98BA37617DE}
$key3={EF745F23AA67243D}
$mz="MZ"
condition:
($mz at 0) and any of ($key*) and filesize < 300000
}
```

Arraylist[1]

```
rule apt_regin_rc5key {
meta:
copyright = "Kaspersky Lab"
 description = "Rule to detect Regin RC5 decryption keys"
 version = "1.0"
 last_modified = "2014-11-18"
strings:
$key1={73 23 1F 43 93 E1 9F 2F 99 0C 17 81 5C FF B4 01}
$key2={10 19 53 2A 11 ED A3 74 3F C3 72 3F 9D 94 3D 78}
condition:
any of ($key*)
}
```

Arraylist[2]

```
rule apt_regin_vfs {
meta:
copyright = "Kaspersky Lab"
 description = "Rule to detect Regin VFSes"
 version = "1.0"
 last_modified = "2014-11-18"
strings:
$a1={00 02 00 08 00 08 03 F6 D7 F3 52}
$a2={00 10 F0 FF F0 FF 11 C7 7F E8 52}
$a3={00 04 00 10 00 10 03 C2 D3 1C 93}
$a4={00 04 00 10 C8 00 04 C8 93 06 D8}
condition:
($a1 at 0) or ($a2 at 0) or ($a3 at 0) or ($a4 at 0)
}
```

and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out [`String.split("regex")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and search for a basic tutorial on regular expressions. They're extremely powerful/useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: if your problem is **only** to "segment" the "rules" in your input, then just do:

```
List<List<String>> sections = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> currentSection = null;

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.startsWith("rule ")) {
      if (currentSection != null) {
        // we are finished with the previous section!
        sections.add(currentSection);
      }
      currentSection = new ArrayList<>();
      currentSection.add(line);
    } else {
      if(! line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        // any non-empty line goes into the current section
        currentSection.add(line);          
      }
    }
 }
} // end of try/while ... I am too lazy to count my braces ;-)
if (currentSelection != null) {
  // make sure to add the final section, too!
  sections.add(currentSelection); 
}
```

But then: you are not very precise about your real *requirements*. I am pretty sure that your real problem is not about "segmenting" that input file.

Most likely, your actual task is to read that file, and for each of the sections within that file, you need to fetch some/all of its content for further processing.

In other words: you are actually asking "how do I parse/process" this input. And we can't answer that question; as you didn't tell us what exactly you want to do with that data.

In essence, this is your option space:

1. If there is really such a fixed layout, then "parsing" boils down to understand "first comes *rule*, then comes *meta*, which looks like ...". Meaning: you "hard-code" the structure of your data into your code. Example: you exactly "know" that the third line contains `copyright = "some value"`. Then you start using regular expressions (or simple String methods like indexOf(), substring()) to extract the information you are interested in.
2. If the file format is actually some kind of "standard" (such as XMl, JSON, YAML, ...) then you might simply pick up some 3rd party library to parse such files. For your example ... I can't say; this is definitely not a format I am familiar with.
3. Worst case, you need write your own **parser**. Writing parsers is a complex, but "well researched" topic, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957873/creating-a-parser-for-a-simple-pseudocode-language) for example.

Comment: Hello. Appreciate your response. I have edited the case which i need it for ultimately. Can you advise me on how can I add each separated rule into arraylist?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I put in some code to give you some ideas how to do that. Please note: this code isn't compiled/tested; dont just blindly copy/paste it. Read it line by line, until you understand what it is **supposed** to do; then adapt your own code accordingly!

Comment: FANTASTIC! You are really good in java. Upvoted your solution